# Get the path of chosen file java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How to display a JFileChooser so I get the absolute path of a file, then assign the path to a string

I was doing something like:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want the `String` representing a `File`?  If you have a `File`, it is generally better to keep it as such than transform it into a `String` representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to complete like:

```
int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(parentComponent); // parentComponent must a component like JFrame, JDialog...
if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
   String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String absPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();

String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
```